# How to draw an editable line in iOS app?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uigesturerecognizer, cgpath

I am developing an app which enable users to draw a connection between different components, I tried to use `CGPath` to draw a line. But the problem is, the line is not an object which I can not reference it later or edit it.

Since I want to enable the app to create a line when two points in screen is touched, and can delete it if need by touching the line, do you have any good ideas to implement this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Try with Bezier Path

Comment: but it's not touchable after generated

Comment: I think then you need to implement everything with logic. Like save all coordinated of line at time of drawing and draw UIView as line so you can access those detail later. I am not sure if it can help as never tried personally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `CAShapeLayer`. You can change its `path` property after it's been added to the layer hierarchy and it will update accordingly.